# USB/RS232 communcation security exception android.permission.sec.MDM_APP_MGMT

Tags: android, serial-port, usb, samsung-mobile, usbserial

I have created an Android app that runs on a Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro (SM-T900). The main feature of this app is RS232/USB communication using the USB host mode and the [USB-to-Serial library](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android).

This app has been working perfectly without the need for any code updates for over a year. However, since the latest Samsung/Android update to Android 5.1, I get a security error and I am no longer able to communicate with USB/RS232 devices. Apart from that, my app runs fine without any crashing. I am simply no longer able to perform USB/RS232 communication.

Here's the logcat:

```
03-24 17:03:09.015 2798-3149/? D/UsbSettingsManager: requestPermission:/dev/bus/usb/002/008 ,packageName com.example.pumpconnector ,pi PendingIntent{338f59ea: PendingIntentRecord{1fd58866 com.example.pumpconnector broadcastIntent}}
03-24 17:03:09.020 2798-3149/? D/ApplicationPolicy: isUsbDevicePermittedForPackage vendorId: 1027, productId: 24577, package: com.example.pumpconnector
03-24 17:03:09.020 13313-13332/com.example.pumpconnector V/MainActivity: java.lang.SecurityException: Admin  does not have android.permission.sec.MDM_APP_MGMT
```

The app has been configured to start whenever a USB device is attached to the device, which still works on the Samsung tablet. The app works perfectly fine on other (non-Samsung) devices. It's fully functioning on a LG Nexus 5 with Android 6.0.1. installed and also on a Moto G with Android 5.1. A little Google search on the exception quickly points to Samsung specific update/bug that prevent USB communication (check [this thread](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=General&messageId=285782)).

I tried to put the following line in the Manifest (without result):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.sec.MDM_APP_MGMT"/>
```

Is there any way to get my app to get the android.permission.sec.MDM_APP_MGMT without having to wait for Samsung to fix it? All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check Knox version on device (maybe have been upgraded between) and follow [migration guide](https://seap.samsung.com/html-docs/android/Content/migration-intro.htm) in knox web site.

Also be sure you'r validating KLM license using [KnoxEnterpriseLicenseManager](https://seap.samsung.com/api-references/android/reference/com/samsung/android/knox/license/KnoxEnterpriseLicenseManager.html#activateLicense(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) and using [EnterpriseLicenseManager](https://seap.samsung.com/api-references/android-standard/reference/android/app/enterprise/license/EnterpriseLicenseManager.html#activateLicense(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) For Basic License. Ofc you should check for  license in receiver with convenient manager.